# How to create a button with a svg inside correctly?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, sass

I created a block with Link and put text and an svg image inside. How do I move it correctly to the lower right corner of the button? (photo)

By the way, how do I change the background color of svg?

It's NEXT.JS framework.
[photo of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiJ4T.png)

TSX:

```
<section className={styles.categories}>
      <div className={`container ${styles.categories__container}`}>
        <Link href='/catalog'>
          <button
            className={`btn-reset ${styles.categories__container__button}`}
          >
            <span className={styles.categories__container__button__text}>
              ВСЕ
              <br />
              ТОВАРЫ
            </span>
            <div>
              <Image
                className={styles.categories__container__button__image}
                src='/img/categories-all.svg'
                alt='Banner Image'
                width={150}
                height={150}
              />
            </div>
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
</section>
```

SCSS:

```
.categories {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 495px;

  &__container {
    position: relative;
    // align-items: center;

    &__button {
      width: 270px;
      height: 216px;
      margin: 10px;
      background-color: #FFF4E7;
      border-color: #B79158;
      border-radius: 20px;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      display: inline-block;
      justify-content: space-between;
      overflow: hidden;
      // align-items: center;
      
      &__text {
        display: flex;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-align: left;
      }

      &__image {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried using png, but for some reason figma distorts my image very much when exporting.

Comment: First of all you cant do anything inside svg (change background for example) if you are using svg like image, use svg tag instead. About position of image you should use some css (flexbox for example)

Comment: This is not React/Next.js related. Solve it with plain HTML/CSS (change your tag to get help from them) first. Adapting to Next.js will be the second step. `<Link><button>...` will result in `<a><button>...` which is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try checking if SVG has been rendered inside your DOM, if its getting rendered then you can try targeting `svg` or `path` from your scss file and apply background color to it

And if its not getting rendered in the DOM itself, then try importing the svg like below

```
import allCategorySVG from 'path-to-svg/categories-all.svg'
```

Then use the imported SVG like following

```
<Image src={allCategorySVG} />
```

Hope this helps